# is it ok to import the same libraries (modules) for each file used in the main program?

Tags: python-3.x, import

My python program has grown large and I want to split it in multiple files. So I want to write some classes in their own file (saved in the same directory as the main application). Apparently this is a common practice.

So I have two files: the main application file, mainFile.py and the class File as myClassFile.py.

in the **mainFile.py** I have the following:

```
import sys
import datetime

from myClassFile import myClass


def Setup(args):

    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    c = myClass()
    c.printTime()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Setup(sys.argv)
```

This program, imports myClass from the myClassFile.py and make it available in the same namespace as the main.

in the **myClassFile.py**, I have the following class definition:

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def printTime(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(now)
```

As you can see, myClassFile.py, uses datetime library, which is not imported. Hence giving me an error. So, an easy solution would be to import it in the same file, but that means that I will have to import all the libraries (or modules) for each new file I created.

So, my question is: should I import all the needed libraries in each file?  is this a good practice in python? would that cause any issues with performance?

Or would it be better to import libraries in the main file and somehow make them available in the imported files?

Sorry If this has been asked before. I couldn't find this particular example anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is new in python I have an answer to my own question. I think it goes like this:

yes, you need to import any library that the new file requires to operate.

The reason is due to namespace. The new file will have its own namespace and it needs to load its dependencies. I think this is the answer. I have been programing in python now and that is what makes sense to me.